# "Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку" VkNet.dll

Tags: c#, vknet

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" в VkNet.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку
> "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не
> удается найти указанный файл.

Данная ошибка выскакивает при попытке получить все фотографии пользователя.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var getAll = vk.Photo.GetAll(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text), true, 20, 0, true, false);

    foreach (var photos in getAll)
    {
        textBox1.Text = photos.CreateTime.ToString();
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема? Авторизация проходит успешно.

Comment: Все же написано - отсутствует файл сборки, т.е. DLL от JsonNet. Проверьте что эта DLL лежит в папке рядом с исполняемым файлом вашей программы и в настройках сборки в проекте указано копировать ее в выходной каталог.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Библиотеке VkNet.dll видимо требуется библиотека Newtonsoft.Json.dll. Установите Json.NET через nuget либо добавьте ссылку в проект вручную. Можно также добавит в проект саму dll, в свойствах указать "Копировать в выходной каталог - Копировать более позднюю версию" и "Действие при сборке - нет"

Comment: Скачал Json.NET напрямую, из папки `Net45` добавил dll в проект, ошибка осталась, только немного другая.. Дополнительные сведения: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" либо одну из их зависимостей. Найденное определение манифеста сборки не соответствует ссылке на сборку. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: @Максим Почему не хотите через nuget попробовать?

Comment: Пробовал, просит обновить nuget (перейти по ссылке, скачать), в итоге при установке пишет: "Для указанного алгоритма подписи не удалось создать SignatureDescription", поэтому хотел в ручную..

Comment: @Максим проверьте, чтобы совпадала версия .NET и разрядность, установленные в проекте, с версией .NET и разрядностью для Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov Пора бы уже открывать сервис, на котором будут храниться сборки и подгружаться если сборка не найдена, как в никсах

Comment: Версия NET 4.5, Newtonsoft.Json.dll тоже брал из папки 45 (писал выше). Похоже, придется как-то решать проблему с nuget, и через него уже скачивать.

Comment: @Максим удалось решить проблему?

Comment: @FoggyFinder, да, оказывается NuGet можно обновить через "Сервис -> Расширения и обновления.." и потом через NuGet уже скачал VkNet нормально. Правда, сейчас выкидывает исключение `VkNet.Exception.AccessTokenInvalidException`, но это уже с кодом что-то..